# Is Flink creating channels in an efficient manner?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-flink

I am inspecting apache Flink code of how it creates connection clients:
https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/io/network/netty/PartitionRequestClientFactory.java#L55-L108

I am trying to think about about the `waitForChannel()` method that times out after 2 seconds:
https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/io/network/netty/PartitionRequestClientFactory.java#L191

I don't like this timeout and I think that if when an `error` occurs or a `partitionRequestClient` arrives a `notifyall()` will suffice.

Am I correct?
Or do we want to constantly trying to connect after a 2 second wait?

Comment: Looks like you're correct from here, that timeout is pretty much useless. I'm hesitant to say for sure because there must be a really good reason to wait for exactly 2 seconds if that's the way it's written.

Comment: This sort of detailed question about Flink's implementation is better suited to one of the flink mailing lists -- probably the dev list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're actually not trying to (re)connect after waiting, we're just re-entering the loop to check for the condition and will wake up as soon as any of the `connectLock.notifyAll()` calls is executed, also before the timeout finishes.

Normally, this gives you the chance to react also on cases where there will never be such a notification but as `xTrollxDudex` above I actually do not see any other places here that may lead out of the loop.